# Issues with AWS Instance domain routing from ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, redirect

I have a pretty basic setup, one AWS instance behind an ELB with SSL Cert.  Domain routing appears to be setup correctly.

When I go to https://example.com I receive .  However, when I go to https://www.example.com I receive code 302.  Not sure where the problem exists but looks like it's on the instance.

Running Flask App on Ubuntu.

Comment: `302` is a redirect. Where is the `302` response trying to redirect you to?

Comment: I'm not sure, it shouldn't be redirecting to anything.  The redirect log is coming from the flask app.  The only difference is the www subdomain but the ELB is routing to the private IP of  the instance.

Comment: Are you unable to examine the response in your browser's debug tools to see where it is trying to redirect you? Please include all the relevant information in your question if you want help.

Comment: Debugs are amazing... lol. Upon inspection the www subdomain was not logged into where the example.com had a logged in session, this forced a redirect to the login page over http which is not allowed.  Thanks!